# how to convert lambda expressions into json string

Tags: c#, json, linq

I have two applications. One application saves options and configurations down as JSON and the other reads the JSON and performs it's task based on the fields in the JSON. Now I want to filter a list that is in application-2. How can I pass how I want the list to be filtered into a string to be stored in JSON and then reinterpreted by application-2?

Is there anyway to serialize linq/lambda expressions and deserialize them? Or is there a better approach like creating a class that contains some filterable options like equal-to, not-equal-to, greater-than, less-than, contains, etc?

Comment: Why not simply implement the filtering in app 2 the way you are doing it (or would have done it) in app 1?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError app 1 interfaces with users that sets the instructions for app 2 and save those instructions in JSON. I want app 2 to be able to perform any instruction read in from the JSON. I was envisioning a form in app 1 that takes a lambda expression that can be read in app 2 and performs that expression on the list. BUT maybe there's a better approach.

Comment: How does app 1 convert what the user enters into a lambda - do you have an example?

Comment: Consider using [Dynamic LINQ](https://github.com/kahanu/System.Linq.Dynamic).

Comment: Another good solution is the Roslyn Scripting package - see [here](https://www.strathweb.com/2018/01/easy-way-to-create-a-c-lambda-expression-from-a-string-with-roslyn/). It can be a bit slow the first time, however. Depending on how you are receiving the filter rules initially, you can build the string, or convert an `ExpressionLambda` to a string.

Comment: what I ended up doing to solve this is create a class that contains an enum of filtering operations like greaterthan, lessthan, equalto, notequalto, in, and notin and target and compared values and convert that into json which can be read in any applications that need to apply those filters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no  way to  serialize and serialize a lamda expression in c#, because it is make in compile time.

The Lamda after the compilation generates a function and the compiler call this function when the lamda expression is used.

You have one option, but is not easy :) Yoy have to store a c# code in json file, and the application-2 will read it, parse it, compile it, and execute it.

But itt will be a complete assembly (like one class) not only one lamdba expression.

If you use :net framrwork here is an example:
https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/715891/Compiling-Csharp-Code-at-Runtime

If you use .Net Core, teh ypu have to use roslyn: https://josephwoodward.co.uk/2016/12/in-memory-c-sharp-compilation-using-roslyn

I hope it helps
regrads

Comment: Bummer. I guess in this case I can just past JSON data about the assembly that can do all the formatting and filtering and have all assemblies follow some sort of contract. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 0):

I found for another solution for this problem. You can store and revert an Expression from string! :)

The only need, the two module (or two program in your case) must be the known the same type.

Sample code:

```
var discountFilter = "album => album.Quantity > 0";
var options = ScriptOptions.Default.AddReferences(typeof(Album).Assembly);

Func<Album, bool> discountFilterExpression = 
                  await CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync<Func<Album, bool>>(discountFilter, options);

var discountedAlbums = albums.Where(discountFilterExpression);
```

Regrads
gy

Answer (score -1):

If you want to filter javascript arrays in pure JSON, you can use [Jpath](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) and [Json.Net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

For example:

```
var token = JToken.Parse("json string here")
var tokens = token.SelectTokens("$.YourJsonArray[?(@.Property == something)]")
```